# How to extract a portion of an image given a particular color?

Tags: c++, c, image, opencv, image-segmentation

[image: PNG image]I have an image (shown below). I want to extract only the pink colored portion and remove the rest of the image. I have the RGB value of pink stored in an array. Is there any way that I can use `bitwise_and` on the image and the color so that I can single out the required portion in OpenCV?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a non compressed image (such as png)? Please don'y convert jpeg to png, but save the image directly in png. jpeg causes compression artifacts that makes this task unnecessarily harder.

Comment: I have saved it in png. but how do I get the result I desire?

Comment: Post the png image please

Comment: ^done, thgh its in a different color

Comment: posted an answer, let me know if this is the desired results.

Answer (score 3):

Bitwise_and is not the right method for this, since it is bitwise. But there are of course methods in OpenCv for this basic task:

If you know the exact value, you can just use the [CmpS](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#compare) method. If you want to find all pink colors within a certain range, use the [InRangeS](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange) method. Optionally change the colorspace of the image first, e.g. if you want to specify your range in HSV space.

Answer (score 3):

Since your *green* color is not uniform, but it ranges from:

```
// in BGR color space
Scalar low(182, 204, 168);
Scalar high(187, 207, 172);

// in HSV color space
Scalar low(72, 43, 204);
Scalar high(72, 45, 207);
```

you can use the [inRange](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange) function. You can adjust the ranges according to the color you need to segment.

Usually HSV color space is better for segmentation tasks based on color, but in this case also the BGR color space is good enough.

This code shows how to get the binary mask of the desired color, and how to copy only the masked portion of the original image in both BGR and HSV color space.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

    // Load image
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");
    {
        // BGR color space

        // Setup ranges
        Scalar low(182, 204, 168);
        Scalar high(187, 207, 172);

        // Get binary mask
        Mat1b mask;
        inRange(img, low, high, mask);

        // Initialize result image (all black)
        Mat3b res(img.rows, img.cols, Vec3b(0, 0, 0));

        // Copy masked part to result image
        img.copyTo(res, mask);

        imshow("Mask from BGR", mask);
        imshow("Result from BGR", res);
        waitKey();

    }

    {
        // HSV color space

        // Convert to HSV
        Mat3b hsv;
        cvtColor(img, hsv, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

        // Setup ranges
        Scalar low(72, 43, 204);
        Scalar high(72, 45, 207);

        // Initialize result image (all black)
        // Get binary mask
        Mat1b mask;
        inRange(hsv, low, high, mask);

        // Initialize result image (all black)
        Mat3b res(img.rows, img.cols, Vec3b(0, 0, 0));

        // Copy masked part to result image
        img.copyTo(res, mask);

        imshow("Mask from HSV", mask);
        imshow("Result from HSV", res);
        waitKey();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example of the mask:

[image]

Example of segmented image:

[image]

Comment: That looks great.Its exactly how I wanted it. But unfortunately for me ,I am using Opencv 2.1 and C... so I can't use the code. I am trying to  use this logic in C. :(
One more thing. I have stored the exact color of the segment( green in this case) in an array. so can I give the same values for scalar high and low?

Comment: @AbhishekV.Pai 1) you specify C++ tag, so this code is C++ as requested.  2) You didn't specify you had an obsolete OpenCV version, so I assumed it was some recent version. You **can't** ask for something and then change the criteria. Also, you're compiling with a C++ compiler, and also the code in your own answer is C++, so I don't get how you are using this in C.

Comment: I'm Sorry that I wasn't being specific. But I really want to thank you for your help. I will upgrade my Opencv and Visual studio and run your code in that. I am using visual studio 2009 for compiling, so I don't know why that particular error is displayed.

Comment: @AbhishekV.Pai I told you this because if you don't write a question specific for your problem, you won't get an answer specific to your problem. If you're getting a new VisualStudio, remember that for 2015 you don't have prebuilt binaries and you need to recompile OpenCV. With VS2012 or VS2103 (better) you are ok.